# How can I write SAP GUI SCRIPT for a SAP pop up window

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, download, sap-gui

I would like to have your help in order to find the solution for the following.
I would like to extract SAP standard invoices to PDF files.
The steps are VF03 - insert billing doc - Menu: Billing Document - Issue output - select the line - print preview - PDF! +  and then I have the pop-up window below.
In the pop up window I would like to press the 'SAVE button' and then save the file with specific filename, which I have already copied to clipboard.

[image]

[image: enter code here]

The code is the following

```
 SESSION.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
SESSION.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/NVF03"
SESSION.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
SESSION.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBRK-VBELN").Text = invoice ' "1094542982"
SESSION.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtVBRK-VBELN").caretPosition = 10
SESSION.findById("wnd[0]/mbar/menu[0]/menu[11]").Select
SESSION.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tblSAPLVMSGTABCONTROL").getAbsoluteRow(0).Selected = True
SESSION.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[37]").press
SESSION.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "PDF!"
SESSION.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
```

Comment: Which SAPGUI version do you have?

Comment: Where can I see the version of SAPGUI ?

Comment: In the [About Box](https://sapbasisdurgaprasad.blogspot.com/2011/09/how-to-find-out-sap-gui-version-and.html) which you find in the SAPLOGON Pad or in any SAPGUI session. You will see a version, build and patch level

Comment: Release 750.   File version 7500.2.5.3376., build 1835159,  patch level 5.  Are the above Ok?

Comment: I was asking because of this [hint](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/03/26/new-scripting-option-in-sap-gui-for-windows-730-pl-8/).

Comment: I have check the hint. But I could not recorder the code. I has tried the following code but ...

Comment: Yes, I tried it myself. Here you cannot avoid windows dialogboxes.

Comment: So how we could handle it!? Is there any way?

Comment: Not really my area of expertise but you probably need to do something like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58779515/6600940)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code in order to print the document to pdf
Any help on this ? 
Control+P have been pressed in VBA window, not in SAP window as I want.

```
    Option Explicit
Public SapGui, App, Connection, Session, SapGuiAuto, wshell, wscript, bWindowFound

Sub SAP()
If Not IsObject(App) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set App = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
   Set Connection = App.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(Session) Then
   Set Session = Connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(wscript) Then
   wscript.ConnectObject Session, "on"
   wscript.ConnectObject App, "on"
End If

Set wshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    Do
     bWindowFound = wshell.AppActivate("PDF Preview")
    Loop Until bWindowFound
    bWindowFound = wshell.AppActivate("PDF Preview")
    'MsgBox ("window found")
     wshell.SendKeys "{CAPSLOCK}"
     MsgBox ("ddd")
     bWindowFound = wshell.AppActivate("PDF Preview")
     wshell.SendKeys "^(p)"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

```
...
Set wshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

n = 1
do
 bWindowFound = wshell.AppActivate("Save as")
 n = n + 1
 wscript.sleep 1000 
Loop Until bWindowFound or n > 10

if bWindowFound then
   wshell.SendKeys "myDocument.pdf"
   wscript.sleep 200
   wshell.SendKeys "{TAB 3}"
   wscript.sleep 200
   wshell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
end if
```

Regards, ScriptMan

Comment: This code belongs in an additional VBS file like in my link, right? Or can you just add it at the end of the VBA script?

Comment: It should be appended to the end of a script.

Comment: Ok, but then we are not talking about VBA or Excel, right?

Comment: If you use the Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue ("00:00:01")) command instead of wscript.sleep 200 or wscript.sleep 1000, you can also use it in VBA.